# Topological entropy in Markov chains

Tags: entropy, probability, stochastic-processes

Given a  finite Markov chain, how do I find the topological entropy $h_T$?
Furthermore, I should compare it with the Shannon entropy $h_S$ and show that $h_T\leq h_S$. Is this a general fact?

This actually comes from an exercise, the specific Markov chain used there is defined by:
$$\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$$ with transition probabilities
$$p_{1\rightarrow 1}=1-q \quad p_{1\rightarrow 2}=p_{1\rightarrow 3}=\frac{q}{2}$$ 
$$p_{2\rightarrow 2}=1-q\quad p_{2\rightarrow 3}=q$$
$$p_{3\rightarrow 1}=1$$

Comment: Does the book the exercise comes from not define what the topological entropy is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend two references:

- Young's [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Entropy-in-Dynamical-Systems-Young/72e68d2510afa78db7de97bb2851c02467e75452) ([e-print](https://www.math.nyu.edu/~lsy/papers/entropy.pdf)), an illuminating conceptual review of entropy in dynamical systems;
- [Pekoske](http://koslicki.math.oregonstate.edu/people/abby-pekoske)'s [Master thesis](https://koslicki.math.oregonstate.edu/sites/koslicki.math.oregonstate.edu/files/MastersPaper.pdf), for its examples with step by step calculations.
  <sub>(Beware of the typo in page 36, though: $h_\mu(\sigma)\approx .075489$ should read $h_\mu(\sigma)\approx 0.32451$.)</sub>

### Topological Entropy $h_T$

> how do I find the topological entropy $h_T$?

From a compatible [topological Markov shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Topological_markov_chain).

The given transition probabilities correspond to the (left) transition matrix:
$$ P =
\begin{pmatrix}
1-q & 0   & 1\\
q/2 & 1-q & 0\\
q/2 & q   & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

We obtain a topological Markov shift (i.e., a subshift of finite type) from the original Markov chain by considering the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $A$ [compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subshift_of_finite_type#Measure) with $P$ (see the posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1040972/418568) and this [talk](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~jeanluc/talks/columbia2010a.pdf)): 
$$ A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The topological entropy of the topological Markov shift [is given](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_entropy#Topological_entropy_in_some_special_cases) (see also [this book](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/9494.html) ([e-print](https://wikis.uit.tufts.edu/confluence/download/attachments/21933250/flp.pdf))) by the logarithm of the spectral radius (i.e., largest eigenvalue modulus, $|\lambda|$) of the adjacency matrix:
$$h_T = \log_2|\lambda|.$$

For $A$ above we have $\lambda=2$ and, thus
$$h_T = 1.$$

### Kolmogorov-Sinai (KS) entropy $h_{KS}$

If $\pi$ is the [steady state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Steady-state_analysis_and_limiting_distributions) of the Markov chain given by $P$, then

$$ h_{KS} = - \sum_{i,j} \pi_i P_{ij} \log_2 P_{ij}. $$

The steady state vector $\pi$ of the Markov chain is the eigenvector associated with the unit eigenvalue of $P$, normalized so that $\sum\pi_i=1$ (see these [examples](https://www.math.drexel.edu/~jwd25/LM_SPRING_07/lectures/Markov.html)). For $P$ above [we have](http://live.sympy.org/)

$$ \pi = \frac{1}{2q+3}\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 1\\ 2q \end{pmatrix}. $$

That yields, e.g.:

$$ h_{KS}(q=1/2) \approx 1,$$
$$ h_{KS}(q=1/5) \approx 0.75464.$$

### Shannon Entropy $h_S$

> show that $h_T\le h_S$. Is this a general fact?

Yes, I think so.

The Shannon entropy $h_S$ depends on the chosen partition and is unbounded, so I'd expect the statement (1) $h_T < h_S$ to be correct. Also, it's possible to have (i) $h_S=h_{KS}$ (e.g., for the [Bernoulli shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_scheme#Properties)) and [we have](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_entropy#Relation_with_Kolmogorov-Sinai_entropy) (ii) $h_T \ge h_{KS}$: from (i) and (ii) we see it's possible that (2) $h_T = h_S$ holds; finally, from (1) and (2) we have: $h_T\le h_S$.

In terms of probabilities $p_i$, we can write

$$ h_S = - \sum_{i} p_{i} \log_2 p_{i}. $$

Calculating the Shannon entropy using $P$'s steady state probabilities, $\pi_i$, we obtain, e.g.:

$$ h_{S}(q=1/2) \approx 1.5.$$
$$ h_{S}(q=1/5) \approx 1.3328.$$

Comment: Nice answer! Can I ask what's the prescription for writing the transition matrix? (and why?) Naively, I'd write down $p_{ij} = p_{i\to j}, which is triangular with largest eigenvalue 1, thus giving zero entropy

Comment: @JohnDonne, Thanks. The largest eigenvalue you need for $h_T$ is of the **adjacency** matrix $A$, not from the transition matrix $P$. About how to write $P$, it's a matter a convention: the one you mention is the *right* transition matrix, the most usual in mathematics (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix)), and then the stochastic vectors are rows; for dealing with matrices I'm more used to column vectors, which I'd guess are common in physics, and that corresponds to a left transition matrix $P_{ij}=p_{i\leftarrow j}$.

Comment: Yes, of course, my mistake. I copied down the wrong transition matrix. Thanks!