# Under dynamic scaling, Ising model emerge fractals, which implicate what？

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, ising-model, chaos-theory, fractals

In the lecture note of statistic field theory of David Tong,

> Fluctuations occur on all length scales, big and small.

he post a link, a youtube video, which describe the Ising model in different scale, especially in Tc, and display the fractal behavior.

So, I want to know does the fractal & chaos have some relationship with many-body physics?

On the one hand, can we use the tools of chaos to describe strong-correlation physics?

On the other hand, could we use semi-classical chaos theory to describe phase transition?

Thanks in advance!
[enter the YouTube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxRddFrEnPc)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There certainly are connections. If you'd like to see some books touching the subject, you can check the question [Statistical Mechanics & Dynamical Systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461138/75633).